# No dual boot screen with XP and Seven

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, hard-drive, multi-boot

I want to install different version of Windows on a PC.

1. I installed Windows XP on a first harddrive.
2. I add a harddrive (HD) on my PC, split it in three part
3. Since I have only one SATA cable, I unplugged the first HD to plug the DVD drive.
4. I installed a working version of Windows Seven on the first partition of the second HD.

I plugged back the two HDs but I have no dual boot screen on startup : Windows XP boots automatically.

**Additional information:** Both system are installed on the same C: drive letter since there is no option during Windows 7 installation processus.

Comment: Is the BIOS pointing at the right hard drive?

Comment: Boot from the Win7 DVD and use `bootrec /RebuildBcd` as detailed [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392).

Answer (score 2):

OSes don't know of each other, that's why you don't have boot menu.

Configure your BIOS to boot from the Win7 hard drive. I won't give you details as it differs between motherboard models.

Then install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and use it to add Windows XP to the bootloader menu.

Comment: seeing my additional information, will-it work if the two system considered themself installed on letter C: ?

Comment: It will work, but you'll have different letters for the same drive (both systems will call their own drive C:)

Answer (score 1):

Since you installed Win XP on one HDD, removed the HDD, installed Win 7 on the other HDD, win 7 does not know about Win XP being installed, similarly XP does not know about 7

You can switch between them for now by changing the primary boot device while booting, but for a long term fix, you will need to play around with your bootloader settings to "tell" win 7 about XP, and then boot via 7, OR reinstall 7 on the same HDD as XP